# setting default value as combination of two different fields in django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and took one project for myself to learn, an Expense Manager ....
Here's my code below:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email=models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name="E-Mail")
    city= models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number= models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

class Data(models.Model):
    borrower_name= models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="the_borrower")
    lender_name= models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="the_lender")
    info= models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="Borrower from Lender")
    witness_name= models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="the_witness")
    money_lended= models.IntegerField()
    date= models.DateField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Data"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.info

class Log(models.Model):
    log= models.ForeignKey(Data)
    status= models.CharField(max_length=15)
    date= models.DateField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status
```

What I want to do is that in `class Data`, I want to set `info` value as the combination of `borrower_name` and `lender_name`...

for example:
`borrower_name= "SHUBHANK"`
`lender_name= "SAMEER"`
then the value of `info` should be

> SHUBHANK from SAMEER

but when I put the code like:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    info= borrower_name + " from " + lender_name
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def __Unicode__(self):
        return self.info
```

the error comes like this:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ForeignKey' and 'unicode'

Help me get rid of this!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `info` a property or method

```
@property
def info(self):
    return "{} from {}".format(self.borrower_name, self.lender_name)
```

You won't be able to use it in any query's but from the way you've shown it, I don't think you'll ever need to anyway.

Comment: thanks!
where shall I put this snippet.. I added it into `class Data`
it showed me an error saying: "Invalid syntax"
error occurred at the return line

Comment: @ShubhankTyagi  -What was the exact error you received? adding it to the class would be correct

Comment: -Problem is solved.. actually by mistake you wrote `rerturn` in place of `return` and I copied it :p
that's y there was invalid syntax...
Thanks a tons!

Comment: @ShubhankTyagi - Sorry! Early morning and not enough coffee consumption yet... No worries